# .htaccess replace question mark

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to replace question mark with slash.
lockalhost/work/gallery?album=pirano => lockalhost/work/gallery/piano
When I go to lockalhost/work/gallery/piano I get a 500 internal server error. How to fix this
Also how to remove .php extension form files. I am using this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But is there any better way to do it?

Comment: look at your server's error logs for details about the 500.

Comment: It says:
[core:error] [pid 5436:tid 1668] [client ::1:48487] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
But it do not now how to use LogLevel debug

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+work/gallery\?album=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /work/gallery/%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRUle ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^work/gallery/(.*)$ /work/gallery?album=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: No, this is still not working. I am getting again "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: @ДиянБогданов Works [perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IV5rW.png). What does your error logs say?

Comment: [core:error] [pid 5436:tid 1668] [client ::1:48487] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: You *are* removing the rules that you already have right? Those are what's causing the 500 error.

Comment: No, with them i also get 500, but i remove them because they are not working to me. I want from this 
URL: "localhost/Workspace/gallery?album=piano"
to become
URL: "localhost/Workspace/gallery/piano"
to view specific gallery. But also to access the page
URL: "localhost/Workspace/gallery"
to view all the galleries

Comment: In my screenshot, the rules do all of that. No idea why it's not working for you.